# How to override the same parent class in 2 classes?

Tags: python, inheritance

So lets suppose there is this in a library -

```
class A():
  ....

class B(A):
  ....

class C(A):
  ....
```

Is there any way to override the `__init__()` in class A before it is inherited by the child classes.
So something like this

```
import A as _A

#Then override the __init__()
class A(_A):
  def _init__():
     .....
     super().__init__()
```

Now I want this class A to be used for inheritance in child classes B and C and not the original A.

Comment: What result does your code give?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Not really clear on your question. My code doesn't give any result. I am looking for a way I can inherit the same parent class to some other classes I import from a library. All the classes A, B and C are defined in the library where B and C are child classes of A. I want to override the __init__() of A so that the change propagates to B and C.

Comment: I can always import the classes B and C similarly the way I imported the class A above and override them. But I would still need to inherit from the original B and C which in turn inherits from the class A in the library. Hence I am stuck.

Comment: You can set "A.__init__" to another function. Calling the original overridden function needs then to store it beforehand (simple "super().__init__" won't work).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you for your response. I couldn't exactly understand what you mean by "You can set "A.__init__" to another function". Could you please explain it in a little more detail, perhaps some pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace functions of a class by others (usually not recommended). E. g. in a separate module:

```
import A.A as _A

old_init = _A.__init__

def new_init(self):
    .....
    old_init(self)

_A.__init__ = new_init
```